# How to associate multiple sets of data to each other and sort in javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have 2 tables with 2 sets of data

```
score - individual name - team name
score 1    name 1          team 1
score 2    name 2          team 1
score 3    name 3          team 1

score - individual name - team name
score 1    name 1          team 2
score 2    name 2          team 2
score 3    name 3          team 2
```

Each  (other than team name, which is only one text input) is a text input where I will input a value.

Lets say the possible score is a value from 1 - 100 and I want to list the players in order from lowest score to highest score in a table on the click of a button.  I also want to associate the players name and there team with their score in the list.  I know how to set the score in an array using document.getElementsByClassName() and list from least to greatest.  What I do not know how to make the players name and team stay with that particular score, even if the score changes and I hit the button again.  I would appreciate javascript only, no Jquery unless it is the only way.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you give us a bit of your code? Specifically, how is the table structured? Is it in HTML?

Comment: Yes it is in HTML and the following code is used multiple times in a few different tables.  Each table represents a team.    
    `<tr>
    <td>
    <input type="text" class="score1"> <!-- score -->
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="text"> <!-- individual name -->
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" id="team1"> <!-- team name -->
    <tr>`

Comment: See these: [**Sort table by price column**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622874/sort-table-by-price-column/15623255#15623255) or this [**How can i use javascript to sort the tables by column?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381735/how-can-i-use-javascript-to-sort-the-tables-by-column-can-not-use-jquery-here/29382433#29382433) or **[Javascript: sorting two similar tables simultaneously**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9962341/javascript-sorting-two-similar-tables-simultaneously/9962614#9962614)